# Pyspark higher-order SQL functions to create histograms from arrays?

Tags: pyspark, higher-order-functions

I have a dataframe with a column of type `array<sometype>`. 
More specifically, `sometype = array<int>` but I suspect this is irrelevant for the challenge at hand.

I'd like to assign to each unique element in the array the number of times it occurs there by using **only higher-order** functions and **in linear time**. The resulting column could be a map or an array of structs - doesn't matter.
For instance:

`["val1", "val2", "val1", "val1", "val3", "val2", "val1"] --> { "val1": 4, "val3": 1, "val2": 2 }`

I tried `aggregate` with `map_concat` (adding a single-element-map with an incremented counter) but the latter turned out to produce a multimap rather than overwrite an existing element with a new value, which foiled the plan.

Any other suggestion how this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this.

```
df.show() #sample dataframe

#+---------------+
#|          array|
#+---------------+
#|      [1, 9, 1]|
#|[2, 2, 2, 1, 2]|
#|[3, 4, 4, 1, 4]|
#|         [1, 4]|
#|  [99, 99, 100]|
#|   [92, 11, 92]|
#|      [0, 0, 1]|
#+---------------+
```

**`Transform`** with **`filter`**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df\
  .withColumn("count",\
          F.expr("""map_from_arrays(array_distinct(array),transform(array_distinct(array),\
              x-> size(filter(array,y-> y=x))))"""))\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+---------------+------------------------+
#|array          |count                   |
#+---------------+------------------------+
#|[1, 9, 1]      |[1 -> 2, 9 -> 1]        |
#|[2, 2, 2, 1, 2]|[2 -> 4, 1 -> 1]        |
#|[3, 4, 4, 1, 4]|[3 -> 1, 4 -> 3, 1 -> 1]|
#|[1, 4]         |[1 -> 1, 4 -> 1]        |
#|[99, 99, 100]  |[99 -> 2, 100 -> 1]     |
#|[92, 11, 92]   |[92 -> 2, 11 -> 1]      |
#|[0, 0, 1]      |[0 -> 2, 1 -> 1]        |
#+---------------+------------------------+
```

Or **`Transform`** with **`aggregate`**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df\
  .withColumn("count",\
          F.expr("""map_from_arrays(array_distinct(array),transform(array_distinct(array),\
              x-> aggregate(array, 0,(acc,t)->acc+IF(t=x,1,0))))"""))\
  .show(truncate=False)

#+---------------+------------------------+
#|array          |count                   |
#+---------------+------------------------+
#|[1, 9, 1]      |[1 -> 2, 9 -> 1]        |
#|[2, 2, 2, 1, 2]|[2 -> 4, 1 -> 1]        |
#|[3, 4, 4, 1, 4]|[3 -> 1, 4 -> 3, 1 -> 1]|
#|[1, 4]         |[1 -> 1, 4 -> 1]        |
#|[99, 99, 100]  |[99 -> 2, 100 -> 1]     |
#|[92, 11, 92]   |[92 -> 2, 11 -> 1]      |
#|[0, 0, 1]      |[0 -> 2, 1 -> 1]        |
#+---------------+------------------------+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

A different way to do this could be if we know **`exactly all the elements`** we will be counting for. This way we can  parallelize better as a struct is like a column and a struct of structs is basically a dataframe inside another.

```
elements=[1,9,2,3,4,99,100,92,11,0]

df.show() #sample dataframe
#+---------------+
#|          array|
#+---------------+
#|      [1, 9, 1]|
#|[2, 2, 2, 1, 2]|
#|[3, 4, 4, 1, 4]|
#|         [1, 4]|
#|  [99, 99, 100]|
#|   [92, 11, 92]|
#|      [0, 0, 1]|
#+---------------+


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("struct", F.struct(*[(F.struct(F.expr("size(filter(array,x->x={}))"\
                                                    .format(y))).alias(str(y))) for y in elements]))\
            .select("array",F.map_from_arrays(F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in elements]),\
                                                       F.array(*[(F.col("struct.{}.col1".format(x)))\
                                          for x in elements])).alias("count")).show(truncate=False)

#+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|array          |count                                                                                |
#+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[1, 9, 1]      |[1 -> 2, 9 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 99 -> 0, 100 -> 0, 92 -> 0, 11 -> 0, 0 -> 0]|
#|[2, 2, 2, 1, 2]|[1 -> 1, 9 -> 0, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 99 -> 0, 100 -> 0, 92 -> 0, 11 -> 0, 0 -> 0]|
#|[3, 4, 4, 1, 4]|[1 -> 1, 9 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 3, 99 -> 0, 100 -> 0, 92 -> 0, 11 -> 0, 0 -> 0]|
#|[1, 4]         |[1 -> 1, 9 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 1, 99 -> 0, 100 -> 0, 92 -> 0, 11 -> 0, 0 -> 0]|
#|[99, 99, 100]  |[1 -> 0, 9 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 99 -> 2, 100 -> 1, 92 -> 0, 11 -> 0, 0 -> 0]|
#|[92, 11, 92]   |[1 -> 0, 9 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 99 -> 0, 100 -> 0, 92 -> 2, 11 -> 1, 0 -> 0]|
#|[0, 0, 1]      |[1 -> 1, 9 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 99 -> 0, 100 -> 0, 92 -> 0, 11 -> 0, 0 -> 2]|
#+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You could also try this(**`to get distinct count per row`**) using structs:

```
elements=[1,9,2,3,4,99,100,92,11,0]
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
collected=df.withColumn("struct", F.struct(*[(F.struct(F.expr("size(filter(array,x->x={}))"\
                                                    .format(y))).alias(str(y))) for y in elements]))\
            .withColumn("vals", F.array(*[(F.col("struct.{}.col1".format(x))) for x in elements]))\
            .select("array",F.arrays_zip(F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in elements]),\
                                    F.col("vals")).alias("count"))\
            .withColumn("count", F.expr("""filter(count,x-> x.vals != 0)"""))\
            .show(truncate=False)
#+---------------+------------------------+
#|array          |count                   |
#+---------------+------------------------+
#|[1, 9, 1]      |[[1, 2], [9, 1]]        |
#|[2, 2, 2, 1, 2]|[[1, 1], [2, 4]]        |
#|[3, 4, 4, 1, 4]|[[1, 1], [3, 1], [4, 3]]|
#|[1, 4]         |[[1, 1], [4, 1]]        |
#|[99, 99, 100]  |[[99, 2], [100, 1]]     |
#|[92, 11, 92]   |[[92, 2], [11, 1]]      |
#|[0, 0, 1]      |[[1, 1], [0, 2]]        |
#+---------------+------------------------+
```

Or, you can use **`map_from_entries`** with structs logic:

```
elements=[1,9,2,3,4,99,100,92,11,0]
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
collected=df.withColumn("struct", F.struct(*[(F.struct(F.expr("size(filter(array,x->x={}))"\
                                                    .format(y))).alias(str(y))) for y in elements]))\
            .withColumn("vals", F.array(*[(F.col("struct.{}.col1".format(x))) for x in elements]))\
            .withColumn("elems", F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in elements]))\
            .withColumn("count", F.map_from_entries(F.expr("""filter(arrays_zip(elems,vals),x-> x.vals != 0)""")))\
            .select("array","count")\
            .show(truncate=False)

#+---------------+------------------------+
#|array          |count                   |
#+---------------+------------------------+
#|[1, 9, 1]      |[1 -> 2, 9 -> 1]        |
#|[2, 2, 2, 1, 2]|[1 -> 1, 2 -> 4]        |
#|[3, 4, 4, 1, 4]|[1 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 3]|
#|[1, 4]         |[1 -> 1, 4 -> 1]        |
#|[99, 99, 100]  |[99 -> 2, 100 -> 1]     |
#|[92, 11, 92]   |[92 -> 2, 11 -> 1]      |
#|[0, 0, 1]      |[1 -> 1, 0 -> 2]        |
#+---------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad,
Thanks, but I think your solution is quadratic and not linear in the number of elements: for each element of the (uniqued) array, you are iterating over the entire array

Comment: not quite sure what u mean by that from a spark perspective, but what i posted should be most performant spark way of achieving this with `spark2.4+` and higher order functions

Comment: Say, you have N elements, and they all happened to be unique. Your first ```transform``` will be applied to all N of them in a row (in my understanding, there's no parallelization at that level). Under each ```transform```, you also have ```aggregate``` that iterates over all N elements. So, you end up performing N^2 operations in total. Compare this with hash-map-based solutions where each update (inner loop) is O(1), and therefore total time is O(N).

Comment: i understand your point. the way i see it it tho is that there is one more option, we could parallelize it better if we knew all the elements we have to count for in a list, using structs. i have updated. u could benchmark both of their performance

Comment: My vocabulary is in the trillions, so explicit enumeration wouldn't work. Here, it is important to find an O(N) solution. I do have some ideas how to solve this in N*log(N) (with sorting), but in regular programming languages (that can update hash-maps), this would be an O(N) task. As my question states, O(N) is the kind of solution I'm looking for with high-order functions. Without it, I can't unfortunately mark the answer as accepted, even though I really appreciate the amount of work you have put into providing it

Comment: I see. I think u are comparing normal programming language functionality to a distributed computing engine. In this case I still think my first solution will b most performant if data is partitioned appropriately, however I am very curious for someone to post a better/faster solution :)

Comment: Hi I've been catching up on this @murtihash would you mind explaining how the acc+IF(t=x,1,0) works. I don't understand what the t = x represent 

Comment: Would it be possible to have a while loop in a hof function? similar to the IF but I've got a iterative algo that stops should stop when the values for the adjustment factors and the index do not change anymore

Comment: something like `SELECT 1 as orig, transform(array(1, 2, 3), (x, i) -> WHILE (x > 4) BEGIN (col1/3) END) as test`

Answer (score 0):

While still hoping to see suggestions for linear time solutions, I'll post here a pretty ugly version that I'm currently using to address the problem in N*log(N):

1. decide whether there's a need for non-trivial aggregation
2. for the cases where aggregation needs to happen:

   2.1. sort the list of elements (this is where the most time will be spent)

   2.2. assign elements that are about to be repeated special null value, while also recording their positions in the sorted list

   2.3. remove elements entries with nulls and shrink the remaining lists

   2.4. from differences in the position values of the remaining elements derive how many repetitions for each n-gram there had been

```
h_df = in_df.withColumn('__isunique__', func.expr("size(mylist)==size(array_distinct(mylist))")) \
            .withColumn('__sorted__', func.when(func.col('__isunique__'), func.col('mylist')) \
                                          .otherwise(func.expr("array_sort(mylist)"))) \
            .withColumn('__coded__', func.when(func.col('__isunique__'), func.lit(None)) \
                                         .otherwise(func.expr("filter(transform(sequence(0, size(__sorted__)), \
                                                                                n->named_struct('p', n, 'e', \
                                                                                                IF ((n>0 and __sorted__[n]!=__sorted__[n-1]) or n==size(__sorted__), \
                                                                                                     __sorted__[n-1], \
                                                                                                     null))), \
                                                                      x -> isnotnull(x['e']))"))) \
            .withColumn('__clen__', func.when(func.col('__isunique__'), 0).otherwise(func.size('__coded__'))) \
            .withColumn('histo', func.when(func.col('__isunique__'), func.expr("map_from_arrays(__sorted__,array_repeat(1,size(__sorted__)))")) \
                                     .otherwise(func.expr("map_from_entries(transform(sequence(0, __clen__-1), \
                                                                                      p -> struct(__coded__[p]['e'], \
                                                                                                  IF (p==0, \
                                                                                                      __coded__[p]['p'], \
                                                                                                      __coded__[p]['p']-__coded__[p-1]['p']))))"))) \
            .drop('__sorted__','__coded__','__clen__','__isunique__')
h_df.show(10,False)
```

```
==>

+------------------+
|            mylist|
+------------------+
|[B, A, A, C, B, A]|
|         [C, D, E]|
|               [B]|
|         [C, C, C]|
+------------------+

+------------------+------------------------+
|mylist            |histo                   |
+------------------+------------------------+
|[B, A, A, C, B, A]|[A -> 3, B -> 2, C -> 1]|
|[C, D, E]         |[C -> 1, D -> 1, E -> 1]|
|[B]               |[B -> 1]                |
|[C, C, C]         |[C -> 3]                |
+------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: i tested ur solution against my first one with `transform with filter`, and it outperformed yours by a significant margin, as i do not sort the array anywhere. also it is much less verbose.